# Powershell commands?

Tags: powershell, posh-git

Ok I'm having trouble and google isn't helping, so I thought I'd come to you geniuses.  I'm using Powershell and posh-git, and it keeps doing something that I'm sure I can exit out of with a magic command, I just don't know it yet.

Basically, when I run git diff (or something else with a long result), it will only give me a screen's worth of information, and end the screen with a colon

```
:
```

And if I keep pressing Enter it will add more to the screen til it is done showing everything for that command, and shows

```
<END>
```

But now what? How do I get out of this and back to calling commands? Enter, Esc and the other things I thought to try are not helping.  I'm sure this must be a simple thing, but I don't know how to explain to Google what I want.

Anyone know?

Comment: Does pressing `q` get you back to the prompt.

Comment: Yay it does! Why is that simple thing so complicated? Haha, Thank you

Comment: Looks a lot like vi style - has nothing to do with PowerShell - it's just command that git diff calls (`less`). You can get the same with any file using `input-command | less`.

Comment: @BartekB so... how do you control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do a `git config -l` you may see some relevant entries like:

```
core.pager='less'
pager.diff=false
pager.log=true
```

You can enable or disable the pager for different commands, or set a different pager.  https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html has the details, check out the `core.pager` section and `pager.<cmd>` sections for specifics.

If you're using 'less' as your pager, hit 'h' at that `:` prompt to get lots of details about what you can do there, and as pointed out by others, q, Q, or ZZ will get you back to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate the current command using CTRL+C. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Well that does the job, but is there a less "violent" way of doing this? I mean, since the command is already done and at the end, it shouldn't be necessary to terminate it exactly